# CodeIgniter Passing a second parameter to a callback

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my database I have multiple types of user depending on the type of account that someone signs up for. I have created a validation rule that checks if the username or email that someone registers which is in the database or not, however I need to be able to check the correct table within the database.

```
function create_account($account_type){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('f_name','First Name','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('l_name','Last Name','trim|required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('u_name','Username','trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[30]|callback_check_if_username_exists');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','Email','trim|required|valid_email|callback_check_if_email_exists');
}
```

My check username callback takes in two parameters, username and account_type. The online help only talks about passing either immediate values or other post values. How do you pass account_type into the callback?

```
function check_if_username_exists($name,$account_type){
    $this->load->model('membership_model');

    $username_available = $this->membership_model->check_if_username_exists($name,$account_type);

    if($username_available){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: From where `$account_type` came from??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the user guide:

> To invoke a callback just put the method name in a rule, with “callback_” as the rule prefix. If you need to receive an extra parameter in your callback method, just add it normally after the method name between square brackets, as in: “callback_foo**[bar]**”, then it will be passed as the second argument of your callback method.

http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks-your-own-validation-methods

So, you'll do it like this;

```
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('u_name','Username','trim|required|min_length[6]|max_length[30]|callback_check_if_username_exists[' . $account_type . ']');
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was a bit unclear. I know how to pass the 'u_name' as a parameter. I'm wondering how to pass 'account_type' as a parameter.

Comment: My mistake, it would still be the same though. Amended my answer.

Comment: I originally didn't have account type being posted but now realise that's probably the best (and possibly only) thing to do. That's what confused me. Thank you though :)

Comment: Ah - OK. You have $account_type as a parameter in your create_account function.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass it directly

```
function check_if_username_exists(){

    $email = $this->input->post('email');// like this way
    $account_type = $this->input->post('account_type');// like this way
    $this->load->model('membership_model');

    $username_available = $this->membership_model->check_if_username_exists($name,$account_type);

    if($username_available){
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Also for check unique entry of email you can use

```
   is_unique[table.field]
```

validation of codignator